# SignalR makes a lot of re-reconnections after migration to asp.net core 3.1

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-3.0, asp.net-core-3.1

After migration from `asp.net core 2.1` to `asp.net core 3.1` `SignalR` behaves in a different way.
After 30 seconds of idle, I get re-connections with negotiating queries like `negotiate?negotiateVersion=1` and my app is stacked for a second.

How to get back the old behavior without extra reconnections ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I found the reason of the problem:

A new param called `ClientTimeoutInterval` was introduced in `asp.net core 3` for `AddSignalR` method. The default value is `30 seconds`.

After I set the following setting:

```
services.AddSignalR(
   hubOptions =>
{
    hubOptions.ClientTimeoutInterval = TimeSpan.MaxValue;
});
```

The problem is gone.